# Photoshop: Batch "Wireframe" Filter

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting

I need to "wireframe" multiple image, over 10,000 and I am looking for the most efficient way to do this. I was thinking of a wireframe filter/effect in PS that will allow me to accomplish this task as a batch.

Although I am not entirely sure this is possible to automate, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Here is an example of a before and after of what I am looking for.

[image: Before] 
[image] "WireFrame"
Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet on your own to get the results you're looking for? The "after" example you posted is a vector drawing that was done by hand, it wasn't achieved with a photoshop effect or filter. I think you'll have a hard time finding a way to "batch" photographs in a way that gets you similar results.

Comment: @Vicki no I haven't tried anything yet. I'm familiar with drawing vectors in illustrator however since this task is overwhelming I figured I should ask the community beforehand. I honestly hope you are wrong :/ but thanks!!

Comment: I'm also not expecting the quality to be perfect as in the after image.

Comment: I hope I'm wrong too! It sounds like a daunting task. Hopefully the suggestion Joojaa posted below will help you. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way you will get that transformation done with that kind of quality. It would be the ultimate goal for [NPR graphics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-photorealistic_rendering), image segmentation, artificial intelligence, reverse engineering and computer vision researchers. An algorithm like this could give you millions just by selling the product to health care professionals or manufacturing plants. If i could do this in a automated way i wouldn't tell you because i could instantly monetize this.

But we can work some way into the problem first if you can guarantee your background colors are that clear and the colors are somewhat constant we could do the following.

1. select constant background with magic wand (20 levels of tolerance),

   - Inverse selection
   - refine selection edge
   - Make a solid color layer
   - Assign stroke

   [image]
2. Run a very tight curves on green channel (or possibly run a color segmentation)

   - Make selection
   - Contract
   - Expand
   - Make a solid color layer
   - Assign stroke
   - multiply

   [image]

All of the above can be done as a action. Edge detection algorithms wont work well because your image has too many non real edges.

Personally i would just draw it in illustrator.